# Execution order in python script?

Tags: python, pbs

I'm suffering from very weird phenomenon.

I'm trying to call a program in python script which is called by pbs script to submit the python job to processors in cluster.
But whenever I use os.system (or subprocess) to call the program in python script, that command executed first ignoring a number of commands above it,which I can see in log file.
More strange thing is when I run the python script interactively just at front node directly (ㅜnot submit the job), then it works fine which means python script itself doesn't have any problem.

I use same the version of python in the pbs script.

Is there anyone who went through this kind of problem?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a bit too broad and without more info / code it's hard to debug. I don't know what pbs is (and i'm lazy) but everytime, a manual-script call works and it does not within some other environment -> check if the environment-variables are the same (usual suspect in cron-jobs and co). It's probably a good idea to print out these environment variables (os.environment ???) within your two approaches

Comment: First, there is not test code publish here. Second,  a residual setup or script in your PBS script may call first overwrite the work and did something that you didn't notice.